# When committing changes WebStorm IDE doesn't ignore files specified in .gitignore

Tags: git, webstorm, gitignore

In .gitignore file I have this

```
#dependencies
/node_modules
```

to ignore `node_modules` folder when committing changes but WebStorm IDE keeps showing changes in the `node_modules` folder. Anyone encountered this?

[image]

I tried this: https://gist.github.com/pavankjadda/2bb6fbdd8786e1f57fd7bcbcc666b51d
But it didn't help

Comment: The files are almost certainly already being tracked by git, and .gitignore doesn't make git ignore files completely, it just makes `git add` and its siblings ignore files so that you don't start tracking them in the first place. However, if the files are already tracked then the only way to stop tracking them is to remove them from your repository (which will essentially also delete those files on everyone's computers).

Comment: `git rm -r --cached node_modules`